# Python Selenium/Geckodriver on Centos7 failing to start: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

- Centos7
- Firefox 68.5.0esr (64-bit)
- Python 3.6.8
- Selenium 3.141.0
- Geckodriver 0.27.0 (Linux 64-bit)

I'm trying to automate some testing for a website using Selenium, but receive this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "guitester.py", line 22, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=gecko_path, firefox_binary=binary)
  File "/home/ian/python3_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/ian/python3_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/ian/python3_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/ian/python3_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ian/python3_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

I have geckodriver in my PATH and have double-checked the versions of all of the software involved. My code is basic:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

gecko_path = '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'
binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=gecko_path, firefox_binary=binary)
```

I've tried it with and without the parameters included for webdriver.Firefox() and get the same exception either way. Other posts have mentioned incorrect versions but my research has indicated that everything I'm using should be compatible. I'm using a python virtual environment.